# Implement a function to traverse ul li Tag in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

An HTML div element contains lists of endangered species grouped by continent and the species population status.

```
<div>
    <ul data-continent="North America">
        <li data-species="California condor">Critically Endangered</li>
        <li data-species="American bison">Near Threatened</li>
    </ul>
    <ul data-continent="Europe">
        <li data-species="Cave bear">Extinct</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to write a function that returns how endangered a species is on a particular continent. For example endangeredSpecies('North America', 'American bison') would return 'Near Threatened'.

Comment: show us you javascript code

Comment: how this value`('North America', 'American bison') `comes from? through search-box or input-box? let us know

Comment: i Wrote a method separately to submit my values...it was a online test question..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be trivial

```
function endangeredSpecies( continent, species )
{
   return $( "ul[data-continent='" + continent + "'] li[data-species='" + species  + "']" ).html();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are the pieces of information that you might need in order to solve that problem:

1. **Attribute Selectors**

   You can select elements based on their attribute names and values. For example if you want to select elements that has a `data-continent` attribute, you can use (using jQuery) `$('[data-continent]')`. If you want to check the value as well, you can do `$('[data-continent="somevalue"]')`.
2. **jQuery `.text()`**

   Given an element that was selected using jQuery, you can get its text content by calling the `.text()` method on it, like so: `$('li').text()`

Using these, you can achieve what you want. I know that I am not answering your question directly, but that's for you to figure out :)

Comment: thanks arnelle-balane for the reply...i used a function to submit my value.

Answer (score 0):

After getting div children, you can filter for ul element that contains the specified continent and then look for li element that contains the specified species.

```
function getStatus(elementChildren, species) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < elementChildren.length; i++) {
      if ($(elementChildren[i]).data("species") === species) {
        return $(elementChildren[i]).text();
      }
    }
  }

function endangeredSpecies(continent, species) {
  var divChildren = $("div").children();
  var i;
  var status = "";
  for (i = 0; i < divChildren.length; i++) {
    if ($(divChildren[i]).data("continent") === continent) {
      status = getStatus($(divChildren[i]).children(), species);
    }
  }
  return status;
}
```